# Properly terminate NodeJS Async Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I wrote the following code to connect to MongoDB wrapped in a Promise, but as soon as it is connected, my NodeJS code is still running / not exit properly. May I know what is the proper way to return or terminate it?

```
function connectDB() {
  return new Promise (resolve => {
    MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function( err, db ) {
      _db = db;
      resolve(db);
    });
  })
}


(async function crawl() {
  const db = await connectDB(); 
  console.log('You are connected');
})()
```

Comment: Most db drivers maintain an open connection with the database after you first connect to the database. This is a performance optimisation and one worth doing since you can lose more than 50% throughput if you need to keep connecting to the database for each request. Therefore there is still one socket open along with eventhandlers to handle data from that socket. This is why node is not quitting. Try closing the MongoClient connection when you are done

Comment: I don't think the problem is with async/await. Does node exit properly when you drop the promises and just call `MongoClient.connect`?

Comment: Yup. Calling db.close() solves the problem, thanks! @slebetman do you want to put that as a solution for me to mark ?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really related to `async`/`await`, it also happens without. As @Torazaburo stated in the comments, the db driver maintains an open connection to the database, and this open socket (along with its eventhandlers) prevents node from quitting. Closing the connection helps:

```
function connectDB() {
  return new Promise (resolve => {
    MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, db) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(db);
    });
  });
}

(async function crawl() {
  const db = await connectDB(); 
  console.log('You are connected');
  db.close();
  console.log('You are no longer connected. Bye!');
})()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering for a good 15 minutes if I didn't understood promises, when it was my mongodb client.

Answer (score -2):

A promise have 2 paramaters: resolve and reject.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

You need to change your promise declaration:

```
return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  // ...
}
```

After that, add return statement to your promise:

```
return resolve(db)
```

Also, i suggest you to add an error log to your promise:

```
if (err) return reject(err)
```

And catch this error.

Good luck!